# How can I enable dictation in Android messaging (texting) apps?

Tags: voice-recognition

How can I enable dictation (voice to text) in Android messaging (texting) apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictation is managed by Input Method when you have downloaded voice recognition offline data for your preferred language at settings, Language and Input, Google Voice typing, Offline speech recognition.

[image: screenshot]

While using the standard keyboard, tap the microphone icon to start dictation.

[image: screenshot]

Or of not available switch input method to google voice typing it will start recognition.

[image: screenshot]